# What is the difference between the terms transformation and map?

Tags: general-topology, transformation

Recently I noticed the usage of **map** in my topology book, and got confused because I already saw the term **transformation** somewhere. Both have the form $T:a\to b$, so what is the difference? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, transformation is linear or affine. The map is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Your answer agrees with Wikipedia, which, among others, has two entries, linear transformation in linear algebra and affine transformation in geometry.